# Android Studio different project settings for multiple projects

Tags: android-studio, coding-style, editor, color-scheme

I have 2 projects "XYZ-Development-Project" and "XYZ-Production-Project".

I want to use different color schemes for each project. There is an option File-> Settings-> Editor-> Color Scheme. But when I change Scheme from 'Default' to 'Dracula', it asks "Do you want to change theme for Entire Android Studio". If I click "NO" it should change theme for only selected project. But theme for all projects is changed.

Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong way ?

Comment: _If I click "NO" it should change theme for only selected project_ - no, it shouldn't. Who said you that it should?

Comment: Then how it should behave on 'Yes' and how on 'No' ?

Comment: Try and see. It's easier for your to see than for me to explain.